# Tortoise SVN: new items not added to project

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2012, tortoisesvn

We are a small team and we are having the same problem over and over.

Say that someone creates a new class for some purpose, and commits the change via Tortoise SVN. When I updated, I indeed see the changes made to the code already included in my project, but I don't have the new class created. I must add it manually to the project.

Is there a way to add those file automatically, or is that a wanted behavior?

Comment: AFAIK this is only possible if you're using TFS or [one of the few SVN plugins for VS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453481/what-subversion-plugins-for-visual-studio-are-there). Tortoise doesn't know/care about VS.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get a Visual Studio plug-in that links the IDE with Subversion.

Visual Studio supports two types of source control plug-in, the older MS-SCCI API and the newer VSPackage API.

As the *author* of [Agent SVN](http://www.zeusedit.com/agent/vs/vsall.html), a MS-SCCI based *shareware* Subversion plug-in, works with Visual Studio.

But there are also a few VSPackage based plug-ins (i.e. I think RocketSVN is one plug-in) that Google should help you to locate.

Answer (score 0):

Your Visual Studio project is defined by a file that tells Visual Studio where to find the files in your project, along with the settings for that project. Find this project file and add it under SVN control.